# Как убрать весь текст после первого абзаца? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как убрать весь текст после первого абзаца?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571288/print-first-paragraph-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что имеется ввиду под абзацем.

```
firstParagraph = textWithParagraphs.split("     ")[0]
```